# animation like vertical scrolling div inside parallax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to do the animation, based on scroll, I already create float-animation in my keyframe. however it doesn't result to the same that I like. I wanted when scroll. then it will be like vertical carousel when scrolling. But the only difference I'm using keyframes and add that class whenever the scroll condition meet. I wanted when I scroll down then the **.div1** will slide up and after the animation complete I wanted to show the **.div2** .Then if the .div2 is current display when scroll up .div2 will animate slide down then when the animation done then .div1 will appear again just like in vertical carousel. Can someone help me. please

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var elementTarget = document.getElementById("scrollTest");

  let lastScrollTop = 0;
  if (window.scrollY > elementTarget.offsetTop + 100) {
    console.log("up 1");
    $(".div2").show();
    $(".div1").addClass("float-anim");
    $(".div1").hide();
  } else {
    $(".div2").hide();
    $(".div1").show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.div2 {
  display: none;
}

.scrollTest {
  position: fixed;
}

.float-anim {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: floatBubble 9s;
  animation: floatBubble 9s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Safari and Chrome*/
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes floatBubble {
  100% {
    top: -100rem;
  }
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes floatBubble {
  100% {
    top: -100rem;
  }
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="scrollTest" id="scrollTest">
    <div class="div1">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f7/eb/d8/f7ebd86ff10d7d738d975f227a591600.jpg" width="50%" />
    </div>

    <div class="div2">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/85/60/5a/85605a84fe1acc6e16ff5a84255b41ab.jpg" width="50%" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: oh sorry, next time i will add snippet . sorry

Comment: the result still same, but i wanted to create a vertical div animation based on scroll.

Comment: FYI, you don't need those vendor prefixes. See https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_animation-fill-mode, for example.

Comment: I understand, but i wanted to make a scroll vertical div. Can someone help me please. I been trying to figure out how will i do that